# Highcharts legend: drag and drop legend items to manually sort series data

Tags: sorting, highcharts, drag-and-drop, legend

Is it possible to drag and drop legend items to reorder the data in chart?

For example we have this order initially:

https://jsfiddle.net/ph7ezsa1/

Then user catches 'Temperature' item in legend and drag it in front 'Precipitation' to change the order in series array and achieve this sorting:

```
    series: [{
            name: 'Temperature',
            type: 'spline',
            // etc...
        },{
            name: 'Precipitation',
            type: 'column',
            // etc..
        }]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ces3o8gh/

It should also be handled outside to preserve the new order on server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but requires some custom code. You can, for example, add a dragging feature through `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `mousemove` events. Finally, changing series order is possible by updating `legendIndex` property.

For example:

```
let startX = 0;
let startY = 0;

let initX = 0;
let initY = 0;

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    zoomType: 'xy',
    events: {
      load: function() {
        const chart = this;

        chart.container.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
          const draggedSeries = chart.draggedSeries;

          if (draggedSeries) {
            const legendGroup = draggedSeries.legendItem.group;
            const mainLegendGroup = legendGroup.parentGroup.parentGroup.parentGroup;

            legendGroup.attr({
              translateX: e.chartX - startX + initX,
              translateY: e.chartY - startY + initY
            });
          }
        });
      },
      render: function() {
        const chart = this;
        const pointer = chart.pointer;

        chart.series.forEach(series => {
          if (!series.customDragAdded) {
            const legendGroup = series.legendItem.group;
            const mainLegendGroup = legendGroup.parentGroup.parentGroup.parentGroup;

            legendGroup.on('mousedown', e => {
              const event = pointer.normalize(e);
              startX = event.chartX + mainLegendGroup.translateX;
              startY = event.chartY + mainLegendGroup.translateY;

              initX = legendGroup.translateX + mainLegendGroup.translateX;
              initY = legendGroup.translateY + mainLegendGroup.translateY;

              chart.draggedSeries = series;
            });

            legendGroup.on('mouseup', () => {
              const draggedSeries = chart.draggedSeries;
              if (!draggedSeries) {
                return false;
              }

              const legendItems = [...chart.legend.allItems].sort(
                (a, b) => a.legendItem.group.translateX - b.legendItem.group.translateX
              );
              const updatedSeries = chart.series.map((s, i) => {
                const index = legendItems.indexOf(s);
                return {
                  legendIndex: index,
                  zIndex: index
                }
              });

              chart.update({
                series: updatedSeries
              });

              chart.draggedSeries = null;
            });

            series.customDragAdded = true;
          }
        });
      }
    }
  },
  ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sfdw6k9y/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#on

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update